# Slow add class on vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have mobile menu and table of contents section on mobile. It shows on mobile with vanilla JavaScript by adding removing class but it takes around one second to show hide menus. I want it to open immediately. What is wrong with my JavaScript?

Site: https://www.dentistryturkey.com/dentist-dental-clinic.html

```
function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you update the question to include a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Instead of one class for `topnav` and another for `responsive` that are mutually exclusive, just have one class that, when present, means one thing and, when absent, means the other. Then, instead of checking the `className` and switching the classes, use `element.classList.toggle("className")`. No, `if` statement needed and no manual modification of `className`.

Comment: Use the [`classList` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead of concatenating class name strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache the element:

```
const topNav = document.getElementById('myTopnav');
```

Use an eventListener:

```
<a href="#" class="icon" id="menu"><small>MENU</small> </a>
```

Script:

```
document.getElementById('menu').addEventListener('click', e => { 
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the click
  topNav.classList.toggle('responsive')
});
```

Comment: I used your example to correct my JavaScript but I figured out the slowness is not because of JavaScript. There was CSS animation which waits for a second which solved the issue.